# Unexpected behavior from wso2 esb during soap to rest conversion

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, wso2, wso2-esb

I have built a proxy service with WSO2 ESB and i want to use it to expose a REST webservice (from some random vendor) as a SOAP webservice to another random vendor. The issue that im having trouble with is that one of the soap methods simply didnt worked. The method in question is "myVendorBpmInsereCliente". What i find really confusing is that the method "myVendorBpmAtualizaCliente" which is pretty much the same thing does work! Im getting error code 405 (http reponse code) because the property mediator "REST_URL_POSTFIX" doesnt seem to append the rest of the path to the uri.

The sequence:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="cadastroMyVendor" transports="https,http" statistics="enable" trace="enable" startOnLoad="true">
<target>
    <inSequence>
        <property name="request_action" expression="get-property('Action')"/>
        <switch source="get-property('request_action')">
            <case regex="myVendorBpmConsultaPeriodo">
                <property name="chave" value="myKey" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property name="datainicio" expression="//datainicio" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property name="datafim" expression="//datafim" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property name="queryparams" expression="fn:concat('consulta/periodo?chave=',get-property('chave'))" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property name="queryparams" expression="fn:concat(get-property('queryparams'),'&datainicio=')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property name="queryparams" expression="fn:concat(get-property('queryparams'),get-property('datainicio'))" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property name="queryparams" expression="fn:concat(get-property('queryparams'),'&datafim=')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property name="queryparams" expression="fn:concat(get-property('queryparams'),get-property('datafim'))" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" expression="get-property('queryparams')" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
                <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="GET" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
                <log level="full"/>
            <case regex="myVendorBpmInsereCliente">
                <property name="chave" value="myKey" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property name="queryparams" expression="fn:concat('cliente/novo?chave=',get-property('chave'))" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" expression="get-property('queryparams')" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
                <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="POST" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
                <xslt key="conf:/repository/scripts/dropTheSoap.xsl"/>
            </case>
            <case regex="myVendorBpmAtualizaCliente">
                <property name="chave" value="myKey" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property name="queryparams" expression="fn:concat('cliente/atualiza?chave=',get-property('chave'))" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" expression="get-property('queryparams')" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
                <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="PUT" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
                <xslt key="conf:/repository/scripts/dropTheSoap.xsl"/>
            </case>
            <default>
                <!-- code omitted -->
            </default>
        </switch>
        <send>
           <endpoint key="gov:/trunk/endpoints/myKey"/>
              <address uri="http://somehost:8080/STL-WS/myVendor/" format="pox"/>
           <endpoint key="gov:/trunk/endpoints/myKey"/>
        </send>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
        <send/>
    </outSequence>
</target>
<description></description>
```

This is what i got from wso2-esb-trace:

`16:26:51,090 [-] [HttpClientWorker-10]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER End : Send mediator
16:26:51,090 [-] [HttpClientWorker-10]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER End : Sequence <anonymous>
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Proxy Service cadastro_myVendor received a new message from : 127.0.0.1
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Message To: /services/cadastro_myVendor
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER SOAPAction: myVendorBpmInsereCliente
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER WSA-Action: myVendorBpmInsereCliente
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Using the anonymous in-sequence of the proxy service for mediation
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Start : Sequence <anonymous>
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Sequence <SequenceMediator> :: mediate()
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Start : Property mediator
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Setting property : request_action at scope : default to : myVendorBpmInsereCliente (i.e. result of expression : get-property('Action'))
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER End : Property mediator
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Start : Switch mediator
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER XPath : get-property('request_action') evaluates to : myVendorBpmInsereCliente
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Matching case found : myVendorBpmInsereCliente
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Sequence <AnonymousListMediator> :: mediate()
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Start : Property mediator
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Setting property : chave at scope : default to : myKey (i.e. constant : myKey)
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER End : Property mediator
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Start : Property mediator
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Setting property : queryparams at scope : default to : cliente/novo?chave=myKey (i.e. result of expression : fn:concat('cliente/novo?chave=',get-property('chave')))
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER End : Property mediator
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Start : Property mediator
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Setting property : REST_URL_POSTFIX at scope : axis2 to : cliente/novo?chave=myKey (i.e. result of expression : get-property('queryparams'))
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER End : Property mediator
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Start : XSLT mediator
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  WARN TRACE_LOGGER Warning encountered during stylesheet parsing : javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: The attribute axis starting at an attribute node will never select anything
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  WARN TRACE_LOGGER Warning encountered during stylesheet parsing : javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: The child axis starting at an attribute node will never select anything
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER output method: xml; encoding: ISO-8859-1
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Using org.apache.synapse.util.jaxp.StreamSourceBuilder
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Using org.apache.synapse.util.jaxp.StreamResultBuilder
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Transformation completed - processing result
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Replace node with result
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER End : XSLT mediator
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Start : Property mediator
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Setting property : HTTP_METHOD at scope : axis2 to : POST (i.e. constant : POST)
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER End : Property mediator
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Start : Send mediator
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Sending message through endpoint : gov//trunk/endpoints/myVendor resolving to address = http://somehost:8080/STL-WS/myVendor/
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER SOAPAction: myVendorBpmInsereCliente
16:26:51,324 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER WSA-Action: myVendorBpmInsereCliente
16:26:51,340 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER End : Send mediator
16:26:51,340 [-] [HttpServerWorker-15]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER End : Sequence <anonymous>
16:26:51,355 [-] [HttpClientWorker-11]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Start : Sequence <anonymous>
16:26:51,355 [-] [HttpClientWorker-11]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Sequence <SequenceMediator> :: mediate()
16:26:51,371 [-] [HttpClientWorker-11] ERROR TRACE_LOGGER Error while building message_`

During another attempt, i added a custom log mediator to log the value of the expression: $axis2:REST_URL_POSTFIX and the result was what i expected: "cliente/novo?chave=myKey". Note that i changed the endpoint in the sequence for ilustrative purposes. Im using WSO2 ESB Version 4.6.0, running as a service. Any sugestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please change the endpoint format to rest and check whether that solves the issue.

Comment: Ok, maybe it wasnt all that unexpected D:. When i changed the endpoint format to "rest" and set the "REST_URL_POSTFIX", everything was appended to the URL but there was side effect: i originally set the endpoint format to POX so it would automatically strip the payload from the soap envelope. I could probably rely on that xslt (its there for that, after all) but is there any reason to why that property works with put method while it doesnt for post?

Comment: There's no any direct relationship between the xslt and endpoint format. If you are calling a REST endpoint we recommend you to use 'rest' as the endpoint format since you are using ESB 4.6.0 version. Anyway for ESB 4.8.* versions you can use HTTP endpoints with relevant REST methods.

Also you can use regular expressions to access the message payload and bypass the soap envelope inside your xslt. For an example '//' will access the message payload directly.

Thanks & Regards,